# Finding a string in a directory listing array

Tags: java, netbeans

I am getting a list of files from a folder on my computer and I put this into an array called `listOfFiles`.

I would like to try find a file name in the folder using a string.

- If it does find the file i need it to say "Matched"
- If it does not find the file (Which is happening now) it says "Not Matched"

My code at the moment keeps saying that it is "Not Matched" even though I have used the exact file name I am searching for.

Code:

```
File folder = new File(txtPDFLocation.getText());
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getName());
    } 
    else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
    }
}

//Try to match file to email address
if(Arrays.asList(listOfFiles).contains("Text1.txt")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
else {
    System.out.println("NOT MATCHED");
}
```

Console:

```
Text1.txt
NOT MATCHED
```

Comment: "contains" is case-sensitive, are you sure the name is exactly same?

Comment: Hey, yes name is exactly the same.

Comment: Use `getname` method, and put the names of `File` object in `listofFiles`  into a `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually cycle it.

You can create new for-loops, or you can even check it in your existing one.

Here is working example :

```
File folder = new File("");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

boolean isItThere = false;
for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        if (file.getName().equals("Text1.txt")) {
            isItThere = true;
        }
        System.out.println(file.getName());
    } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Directory " + file.getName());
    }
}

//Try to match file to email address

if (isItThere) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
} else {
    System.out.println("NOT MATCHED");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

listOfFiles is of type Files, not Strings

Comment: Is there a way to pass it to a string?

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep the Name of the files as a String. Assuming you are searching in a folder which doesn't contain any file with the same name. So maybe it is more easy to use HashSet or Map. They got contains() method and seek through the Table in O(1).